# Is there an equivalent to windows+p hotkey (change between mirrored/extended monitor) in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

In Windows, Windows Key + P changes how an attached monitor is attached. I primarilly used it to swap between mirrored and extended views.

Is there a similar hotkey in Ubuntu 14.04?

To clarify, I'm often in the situation where my built-in display is blank after being plugged into HDMI and suspendend. I think it just needs to be told to switch to a different display mode. I can't do this with a command, as I can't see what I'm typing.

I've googled, and my google fu doesn't appear to be working well

Comment: Now there is a Super+P at 20.04 LTS! Hurray!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a simple built-in shortcut, you can do what I do on Xubuntu and use `xrandr` to switch the display output. All of this might seem like a pain in the ass, but I've found it to be rock solid reliable over the years (especially compared to relying on display auto-switching).

```
$ sudo apt-get install xrandr
```

So on my setup, this command switches to mirrored output:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VIRTUAL1 --off \
--output DP1 --off --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2040x0 --rotate normal \
--same-as HDMI1 --output VGA1 --off
```

And this one switches to extended desktop:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VIRTUAL1 --off \
--output DP1 --off --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2040x0 --rotate normal \
--output VGA1 --off
```

Obviously, these commands are too long to be typing in, so I save them to scripts called `display_TV_mirror.sh` and `display_TV_extend.sh`, and then I bind a shortcut key to each script. In regular Ubuntu, I *think* you can set the shortcuts in  **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts**. I use to separate scripts with two separate shortcut keys, but you could easily combine them into one switch with some toggle logic.

Note: To find out the exact command you want to use for xrandr, it is probably easier to use `arandr` at first, which is basically a gui interface to xrandr.

```
$ sudo apt-get install arandr
$ arandr
```

Then you can set up your desired config, save it to a file somewhere, then look at that file to find out what xrandr command is needed to get the setup you want.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my setup, I can switch monitor mirroring on with this command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --same-as DP1
```

To turn off monitor mirroring, I use this command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --pos 1920x0
```

In other words, I don't need to re-specify settings such as "--mode 1920x1080" and "--rotate normal". Simply changing between "--same-as" and "--pos" has been sufficient, at least in my case.

These commands have been handy for me when viewing my workplace screens from a remote laptop. My workplace screens are on a dual-monitor setup running Linux Mint, so I need an easy way to temporarily switch to mirror mode during my remote session. I can also switch mirroring on and off using the "Super-p" (Windows-p) Cinnamon keyboard shortcut ("Re-detect display devices"), but the keyboard approach sometimes crashes my VNC.